# Working on dotted line span and I can't figure out how to make it same line

Tags: html, css

```
  dl {
     width: 480px;  
  }

  dt {
     float: left;
     clear: right;
     width: 100%;   
     background: url(http://galeon.sourceforge.net/twiki/pub/TWiki/TWikiDocGraphics/dot_lr.gif) repeat-x 0 180%;   
  }

  dt span {
     background: #fff;   
  }

  dd {
     float: right;
     width: auto;   
  }


  <dl>
      <dt><span>Phone</span></dt>
      <dd>123-4567</dd>

      <dt><span>Email</span></dt>
      <dd>info@email.com</dd>    
  </dl>
```

I am trying to make it so i can have a dotted line span through the middle of my text but i am having trouble with the width of the dots, for some reason the text keeps going to the next line after the dots.

You can see what i mean here

http://jsfiddle.net/MUqYn/16/

Comment: The dt element is set to 100% width, where else would the dd element go?

Comment: Can i just make it so it goes until the text and stops there?

Comment: Should the dotted line also be below the value (`<dd>`), or stop before it?

Comment: The dotted line and the text on the right should all be one line.. it would be like email:.....888-888-8888 all on one list but with the dots just expanding to the end. i cant figure out without making it go to a second line..

Comment: And i need it to change as the site changes cause it seems a little diff on browsers

Comment: There's also this, but it feels dirty: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dwCmg/1

Not exactly what you hoped for (different markup), but it seems to work well on all major browsers. The idea is basically to use tables:

HTML:

```
<div class='definition'>
    <span class='name'>Phone</span>
    <span class='dots'></span>
    <span class='value'>123-4567</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.definition {display:table; width:480px;}
.definition > span {display:table-cell; white-space:nowrap;}
.definition > span.dots {width:100%; background: url(http://galeon.sourceforge.net/twiki/pub/TWiki/TWikiDocGraphics/dot_lr.gif) repeat-x 0 180%;}
```

Comment: You could also replace the background attribute with border-bottom: thin dotted; and avoid the need for an image.

Comment: @John - Excellent point! I did think about it when I first saw the question, but then completely forgot about it... Thanks! Here's a version with dots as a border: http://jsfiddle.net/dwCmg/4/ . We can add another element to control the position of the line, so it isn't too low.

Comment: Another note: this solution will not work on old browsers - I think it should work on IE8 though.

Comment: It works flawlessly! Thank you! now i finally know how to approach this problem!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. These CSS3 features were sitting on the shelf for too long... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to approach the problem using a negative margin-top on the dd elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/newspark/KvpCM/1/

Comment: try adding a white background color to the dd. It worked for me. http://jsfiddle.net/newspark/KvpCM/2/

Answer (score 1):

As was said, you are pushing the `dd` to the next line by making the `dt` have 100% width...

If you let the left-floated `dt` have its normal width and just make the `dd` have the 100% width and background instead, it should work fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/aneves_sw/meKhe/

You just need to get a new image, 1px per 2px, with a dot and a white-space to its right,
so that you don't need to juggle with background-position.